# phpWord add chart to location specified by a variable on a template

Tags: php, laravel, phpword, phpoffice

I'm trying to insert a chart into an existing .docx file, somewhere in the middle of the file.

There are other sections where I had to insert numbers generated by my code which I just did using the `${variable}` method and using `$doc->setValue('variable',$content)`

However now I need to insert an entire chart in the middle somewhere and can't use `addSection`

Is it possible to put a chart into a docx by using something like `setValue` ? (but not setValue because that needs a string not an object)

I found this attempt from 2013 but no good: [PHPword insert table in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538007/phpword-insert-table-in-template)